# PowerShell: Programmatically deleting AD SRV records that contain any upper case characters

Tags: powershell, dns, active-directory

Using PowerShell and running it as an Administrator with Domain Admin credentials, I am trying to programmatically delete AD SRV records containing any upper case characters, rather than clean up these records manually and individually.  The problem first appeared with the introduction of Windows Server 2016 into an AD domain that had Windows 2012 (and below) DCs.  I've been banging my head trying to revise the code below and worked through wrong RegEx and wrong variables, and now I am at the point where I'm almost to the finish line but the code at this point is reporting that its unable to delete records which match condition of upper case characters.  The latest code is below, followed by a snippet of the latest results, and finally, a snippet of the raw data the code is working against.  Before you ask, hotfixes to fix this problem on Windows Server 2016 have long been installed as well as Group Policy settings in place to prevent it, however the upper case SRV records still tend to re-insert themselves from time to time and at this point I'm resorting to PowerShell for cleanup.  It's a lab anyway, and the task of creating the PowerShell has now become itself the point of the exercise; and I'm fine with that.  Any thoughts on where I am going wrong below?  Thank you for reading.

**Latest Code:**

```
Clear-Host
# DNS zones to examine
$zoneNames = @("_msdcs.alpha.local", "alpha.local")
# DNS server to query
$dnsServer = 'dc2.alpha.local'
# Get all SRV records from the specified zones
$allSrvRecords = foreach ($zoneName in $zoneNames) {
    Get-DnsServerResourceRecord -ZoneName $zoneName -RRType SRV -ComputerName $dnsServer
}
# Array to store deleted records
$deletedRecords = @()

# Iterate through all SRV records
foreach ($record in $allSrvRecords) {
        if ($record.RecordData.DomainName -cmatch '[A-Z]') {
        try { # Attempt to delete the record
            Write-Host "Attempting to delete record: $($record.HostName) in zone $($ZoneName)"
            Remove-DnsServerResourceRecord -Name $record.HostName -RRType $record.RecordType -RecordData $Record.RecordData.DomainName -ZoneName $ZoneName -ComputerName $dnsServer -Force
            $deletedRecords += $record
            Write-Host "Deleted record: $($record.HostName) in zone $ZoneName"
        } catch {
            Write-Host "Error deleting record: $($record.HostName)"
            Write-Host "Error details: $_"
        }
    }
}
# Output results
Write-Host "Deleted records:"
$deletedRecords | ForEach-Object { $_.HostName }
```

**Latest Results Snippet:**

```
Attempting to delete record: _kerberos._tcp.Site1._sites.dc in zone alpha.local
Error deleting record: _kerberos._tcp.Site1._sites.dc
Error details: InputObject for resource record has an invalid value. Failed to remove the resource record on dc2.alpha.local server. Please check extended error for additi
onal details.
Attempting to delete record: _ldap._tcp.Site1._sites.dc in zone alpha.local
Error deleting record: _ldap._tcp.Site1._sites.dc
Error details: InputObject for resource record has an invalid value. Failed to remove the resource record on dc2.alpha.local server. Please check extended error for additi
onal details.
Attempting to delete record: _kerberos._tcp.Site3._sites.dc in zone alpha.local
Error deleting record: _kerberos._tcp.Site3._sites.dc
Error details: InputObject for resource record has an invalid value. Failed to remove the resource record on dc2.alpha.local server. Please check extended error for additi
onal details.
Attempting to delete record: _ldap._tcp.Site3._sites.dc in zone alpha.local
Error deleting record: _ldap._tcp.Site3._sites.dc
Error details: InputObject for resource record has an invalid value. Failed to remove the resource record on dc2.alpha.local server. Please check extended error for additi
onal details.
Attempting to delete record: _kerberos._tcp.dc in zone alpha.local
Error deleting record: _kerberos._tcp.dc
Error details: InputObject for resource record has an invalid value. Failed to remove the resource record on dc2.alpha.local server. Please check extended error for additi
onal details.
```

**Raw Data (that the code is working against) Snippet:**

```
HostName                  RecordType Type       Timestamp            TimeToLive      RecordData                                        
--------                  ---------- ----       ---------            ----------      ----------                                        
_gc._tcp.Site1._sites     SRV        33         3/16/2024 4:00:00 AM 00:10:00        [0][100][3268][DC1.ALPHA.local.]                  
_gc._tcp.Site1._sites     SRV        33         3/14/2024 9:00:00 AM 00:10:00        [0][100][3268][dc1.alpha.local.]                  
_kerberos._tcp.Site1._... SRV        33         3/16/2024 4:00:00 AM 00:10:00        [0][100][88][DC1.ALPHA.local.]                    
_kerberos._tcp.Site1._... SRV        33         3/14/2024 9:00:00 AM 00:10:00        [0][100][88][dc1.alpha.local.]                    
_ldap._tcp.Site1._sites   SRV        33         3/16/2024 4:00:00 AM 00:10:00        [0][100][389][DC1.ALPHA.local.]                   
_ldap._tcp.Site1._sites   SRV        33         3/14/2024 9:00:00 AM 00:10:00        [0][100][389][dc1.alpha.local.]                   
_gc._tcp.Site2._sites     SRV        33         3/14/2024 8:00:00 AM 00:10:00        [0][100][3268][dc2.alpha.local.]                  
_kerberos._tcp.Site2._... SRV        33         3/14/2024 8:00:00 AM 00:10:00        [0][100][88][dc2.alpha.local.]
```

Comment: I believe you need to specify the rest of the SRV RecordData items as well; example from Microsoft's documentation below. Note although the records return with square brackets, when sending you need to comma separated strings:
`Remove-DnsServerResourceRecord -RRType SRV -Name "_misc._tcp" -ZoneName "_msdcs.contoso.com" -RecordData "0","10","1234","1.1.1.1."`

Comment: Try `$record |Remove-DnsServerResourceRecord -ComputerName $dnsServer -Force` instead

Comment: Wait, why is this a problem exactly? DNS is case-insensitive and has always allowed upper-case characters – do those records actually create a problem on your network?

Comment: @user1686 - so what do you think happens when one DC has more SRV records in DNS than another one, because it is registering records also in upper case but another one is not.   Think about it for a second...and then after doing so you correctly guessed that it will be unduly hit with requests more often than another one without the extra superfluous records in DNS then ..... congratulations... you win a prize.   If you research this problem, you'll notice, as I stated in my question, that this has been a problem with the introduction of Windows Server 2016.

Answer (score -1):

By default NetLogon service working on Domain Controllers periodically registers related Domain Controller DNS resource records on the DNS Server service. Even if you delete the DNS records, this service will re-register the DNS records which are crucial for the Active Directory domain to work correctly.

Ref: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/networking/enable-disable-dns-dynamic-registration
Edit:
As per https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/troubleshoot/windows-server/networking/dns-registers-duplicate-srv-records-for-dc
"To work around this issue after you encounter it, you have to rename your DCs by using all lowercase characters." taken from the article.

Comment: That would be a correct statement but -1 for not addressing the OP's question

Comment: If you read my question closely you'll see that I put into place a GPO to prevent it.  That wasn't working up to snuff so, I made the script... to periodically clean the environment

Comment: I did not see the word duplicate in the problem description, I haven't realized duplicate SRV records.  I have understood the case in more detail now and updated the answer..